# Django: Crispy Forms Validation Error in Template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-crispy-forms, django-validation

I'm using `django-crispy-forms` for nicely rendered forms.
For one of my forms, I had to make some custom adjustments and am now wondering how to properly validation errors that don't belong to a specific field but to the whole form.

Specifically, my form contains a start and end date:

```py
# forms.py 
class PlotForm(forms.Form):
    start_date = forms.DateField(initial=last_month, widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    end_date = forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today, widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        start_date = cleaned_data.get('start_date')
        end_date = cleaned_data.get('end_date')
        if start_date > end_date:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Start date must not be before end date.")
        return start_date
```

To check that the end date is not before the start date, I use `clean(self)`.

However, the error is never displayed.

```html
<form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                {{ form.start_date|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                {{ form.end_date|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

I can fix this by adding `{{ form.errors }}` but that looks really ugly. Is there any simple way to nicely render form-related validation errors with `crispy`?
The field-related errors are shown nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [**`|as_crispy_errors`** template filters [readthedocs]](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/d-0/api_templatetags.html#templatetags.crispy_forms_filters.as_crispy_errors):

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|as_crispy_errors }}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            {{ form.start_date|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            {{ form.end_date|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This template filter will:

> Renders **only form errors** the same way as `django-crispy-forms`.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73251040/12199738
Simplest solution was just adding the novalidate attribute to my form.